# Arduino Library in ChibiOS

Tags: arduino, rtos, chibios

Can I use an Arduino library such as [OneWire](https://www.pjrc.com/teensy/td_libs_OneWire.html) in the [ChibiOS](http://www.chibios.org/) RToS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can ask [Bill Greiman](https://github.com/greiman) directly by filling an issue in the [ChibiOS Arduino Repo](https://github.com/greiman/ChibiOS-Arduino) :)